Using "Symmetrical difference" for multiple layers at once in QGIS
I have four different layers (Parks, Forest, Sports ground, Nothing) inside my city analysis and I want to make several different new layers out of them.
I want to find out, which places have which layers active there. Nothing? -> Red color Only Parks|Sports Grounds|Forest? -> Bright green|blue| Red color. Places with overlap of multiple get separate colors.
Creating all these new layers is really tedious and I can already see, that "symmetrical difference alone" won't work there.
How can I make "symmetrical difference" work for multiple operations at the same time (e.g a park is in this area but has NO sports fields and NO forests and using sym. dif. doesn't really work on the second time, bc it reads sports fields at some spots)?

Look at the overlap analysis tool.  After running it you could add a field which you will symbolize, (see categories); then select the records that match each value you want to symbolize and use the calculator to populate that field.  You could also look at the multiple union tool which will give you the information you need, and process that with a selection and calculation,  Someone could put this in a script to avoid multiple selections and calcuations but there's not many of them.

Create a column in each layer named type with data type text and with the value 'Park' for park layer, 'Sport' for sport layer etc.
Then Union Multiple with one of the layers as input layer and the other three as Overlay layers:

The output will be a layer of all geometries and four columns: type, type_2, type_3, type_4.
Style the output using the expression: concat( "type",' | ', "type_2",' | ', "type_3",' | ', "type_4",' | ')

You can extract or select different combinations from the output.
